# How to combine Actor.setPosition and Actor.hit?

Tags: libgdx

Why after using Actor.setPosition, input coordinates in Actor.hit come with a shift in the values ​​specified in setPosition?

Create scene:

```
public class MyActor extends Actor {
...
    int width = 70;
    int height = 70;

    public MyActor(Texture img, int x, int y, int realX, int realY) {
...
        sprite = new Sprite(img, x, y, width, height);
        this.setPosition(realX, realY);
```

Standard search Actor:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        Vector2 coord = stage.screenToStageCoordinates(new Vector2((float)screenX,(float)screenY));
        Gdx.app.log("touchDown", "" + coord.x +","+ coord.y);

        selectedActor = (MyActor)stage.hit(coord.x,coord.y,false);
```

...

```
public class MyActor extends Actor {

    @Override
    public Actor hit(float x, float y, boolean touchable) {
        if(!touchable)
            Gdx.app.log("Actor.hit:", "" + x +":"+ y);
        return x < getX()|| x >= getX() + width || y < getY()||  y >= getY() + height ? null : this;
```

But come the distorted values.

Coordinates Click:  touchDown: 26.25,81.250015.

MyActor in the values ​​obtained from the offset, the multiple of 70:

- Actor.hit: -43.75:11.250015
- Actor.hit: -43.75:81.250015
- Actor.hit: 26.25:11.250015
- Actor.hit: 26.25:81.250015

Why? How to fix?

`UPDATE`

```
public class MyStage extends Stage {
...
    @Override
    public Actor hit(float x, float y, boolean touchable) {

        return super.hit(x,y,touchable);
```

Comment: The real question is : *why is your hit method called 4 times after the touchdown?*

Comment: 4 actor in a stage. This log for all actors. But x, y (click) should be one.

Comment: Then don't you think you forgot to show us the `stage.hit` method?

Comment: @realUser404, I used the native method. `return super.hit(x,y,touchable);` He does the same thing?

Comment: I think you should try to call `stage.touchDown` instead of `stage.hit`. Does it make any difference?

Comment: @realUser404, are two different things. stage.touchDown - is to click on the screen. stage.hit - search for collections of actors. IMHO.

Comment: The easy way to know what is happening is putting a breakpoint in the `actor.hit()` method. You can then browse the callstack to see where the method is called and where the `x` and `y` are set or changed.

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing the same problem.After a couple of trial and errors, I have solved the problem in my game. Ever since, using **actor.setPosition(x,y)**, all my clicks obtained from the functions **Gdx.input.getX()** and **getY()** (left clicks in my case), was shifting the origin to x,y. It was as if **setPosition()** was acting as some sort of **setOrigin()** function.
These were the changes I had made, since the problem. One or more of these changes could solve your problem:

- Setting the input processor as (this), instead of the stage.
- Using your **coord** variable as Vector3 and passing it through **camera.unproject(coord)**, to obtain values in world co-ordinates. This makes the clicks independent of any localized reference frame.
- Removing **stage.screenToStageCoordinate**s function, as a natural consequence of converting **coord** to Vector3. Moreover, point no 2 deals with the conversion factor.